# Issue frame received per second on server side

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, python-3.5, zeromq

I have the following code client sending frames to server. I need to calculate the difference in the number of frames sent from client and received on a server per second.
In my current code I have the client sending frames per second sent which works fine, currently, client is sending 16 frames and server is receiving is 15 frames per second. But on the server side it's not calculating proper frames per second received. If I sent task size to 15 but if I set it to more than it will receive more and for most of the time on server-side I will receive 0.0 frames per second. Note If I remove async and opt for threads I retrieve 1 frame per second which is very slow. Help is highly appreciated Thanks

Client side

```
FPS = 25
context = zmq.Context()
server = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
server.connect(SERVER_A_ADDRESS)
destination = {"currentSocket": server}
running = True
frame_requests = 0
def data_rate():
  global destination, running, frame_requests
  while running:
    before_sent = frame_requests
    time.sleep(1)
    after_sent = frame_requests
    print("{} ( i ) : send frames: {} per second.".format(strftime('%H:%M:%S'),round((after_sent - before_sent) / 1, 2)))   
def send_frame(frame, frame_requests):
   global destination, running
   try:
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224))
    encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
    destination["currentSocket"].send(jpg_as_text)
   except Exception as Error:
    print(Error)
    running = False
def main():
  global destination, running, frame_requests
  interval = 1 / FPS
  while running:
    for img in filenames:
        frame = cv2.imread(img)
        frame_requests += 1
        threading.Thread(target=send_frame, args=(frame, frame_requests)).start()
        time.sleep(interval)
    running=False
  destination["currentSocket"].close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
 threading.Thread(target=data_rate).start()
 main()
```

Server-side

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
dest_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
socket.bind(SERVER_ADDRESS)
dest_socket.connect(DEST_SERVER_ADDRESS)
tasks=20
running = True
count=1
async def forward_data(frame, count):
   global m1, m2
   source = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(base64.b64decode(frame), dtype=np.uint8), 1)
   image = img_to_array(source)
   image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
   preds = m1.predict(preprocess_input(image))
   serialized_preds = pickle.dumps(preds)
   compressed_preds = zlib.compress(serialized_preds)
   dest_socket.send(compressed_preds)

def data_rate():
  global  count,running
  while running:
    before_recv = count
    time.sleep(1)
    after_recv = count
    print("{} ( i ) : sending frames: {} per second.".format(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'),round((after_recv - before_recv) /1 , 2)))
async def main():
  global dest_socket,count
  tasks = []
  while True:
    try:      
           frame = socket.recv_string()
           count += 1
           print("{} ( + ) :  Received frame {} from {} successfully.".format(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'),count,CLIENT_TITLE))
           task = asyncio.ensure_future(forward_data(frame, count))
           tasks.append(task)
           if len(tasks) >= 20:
                await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
                tasks.clear()
     except Exception as error:
        print(Error)
        break
  socket.close()
 if __name__ == "__main__":
  threading.Thread(target=data_rate).start()
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output

```
#########################
19:41:25 ( i ) :frames: 20.0 per second.
#########################
19:41:25 ( + ) :  SERVER B received array 2 successfully.
19:41:25 ( i ) :  Sending array 3 to SERVER B...
19:41:26 ( + ) :  SERVER B received array 3 successfully.
19:41:26 ( i ) :  Sending array 4 to SERVER B...
#########################
19:41:26 ( i ) :  frames: 0.0 per second.
#########################
19:41:26 ( + ) :  SERVER B received array 4 successfully.
19:41:27 ( i ) :  Sending array 5 to SERVER B...
#########################
19:41:27 ( i ) : frames: 0.0 per second.
#########################
```

Comment: You didn't show how you are calculating (ensuring) the sending frame rate in the client.

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342, please have a look at the updated post I have updated.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the fact that you buffer 20 tasks before you forward (process) any of them. Also, what's `recv_string` - since you don't `await` it, it looks like a blocking function in the middle of asyncio code, which could cause all kinds of issues.

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342, you are pointing out to me to exactly the right direction. If I set buffer to 5 then five frames are being received, there must a drop of frames so how to overcome this? Because in the literature I read processing latency and network has impact on frame drop rate

Comment: I don't think you are dropping frames, but you might be miscounting them. Since you didn't show `forward_data` and since `recv_string` appears blocking, any number of things could be going wrong. I can only advise that you stick to async (non-blocking) code inside async functions.

Comment: @user4815162342, thanks I have updated the code. frames are not being dropped but at the rate, the server should retrieve must be less than client sending rate. If use thread instead of  asyncio, I retrieve very fewer frames in one second for instance if client rate is sending 16 frames server will receive 1 or 2 frames per second

Comment: But why even use asyncio if you're still using blocking code? That can't possibly work and you're not gaining anything.

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342, I have removed buffer and asyncio, only using async functions, and would you please elaborate little bit blocking code I think my code is not blocking because I am using coroutines

Comment: I think you misunderstand how asyncio works. Unlike threading, asyncio won't make your code non-blocking just because you put it inside `async def`. For asyncio to work, you need to replace calls to blocking functions with awaits of async ones. For example, one would replace `time.sleep(1)` with `await asyncio.sleep(1)`, or `requests.get(url)` with `await aiohttp_session.get(url)`. I don't know what APIs you use, so I cannot do that for you. I also can't guarantee that that'd fix your issue because I don't know precisely what the issue with your code is, I can only guess.

Comment: Can you explain why you use asyncio in the first place? `forward_data` doesn't await anything, so it has no hope of being run in parallel. Literally everything you do is sync. Without asyncio in the picture you might find it easier to debug your code.

Comment: Hi @user4815162342, would you please tell me what should I do to receive more frames in one second on server? I am receiving 1 or 2 frames per second on the server side?

Comment: I'd first get rid of asyncio, which adds to the confusion without bringing any value. Then I'd comment out the `dest_socket.send` line in `forward_data` to check whether the destination server is slowing things down. If that doesn't help, I'd check whether some of the transformations (pickle, compress, etc.) are slowing things down, by commenting them out one by one. If that doesn't help, it'd look like a network issue. It's hard to give a more concrete recipe - at this point you're asking us to debug your code for you, and that's just not how this site works.

Comment: Thank you very much you really helped me a lot @user4815162342, I really appreciate your time and help, I figured it out that pickle and compress are slowing down the number of frames read per second